# CALayer "floating" within NSScrollView?

Tags: calayer, nsscrollview

I'd like to have a `CALayer` "float" over my scroll view's documentView. That is, it shouldn't move during scrolling.

If I add a CALayer to my `NSSCrollView`'s layer, the added layer is masked by the clipview: in only shows where the scrollers are.
Adding the layer to the clipview doesn't work either. It's masked.

I could add the layer to the document view and compensate the scrolling so that it stays in place, but that would be inelegant.

Comment: Add the layer outside the scroll view? Add a floating subview? Does the clipview and/or document view draw background?

Comment: I am thinking about adding the layer to the scrollView's superview, but this would be less robust (the scrollview may move independently from other views). And since my scroll view is already subclassed, this would have been easier. I would rather avoid adding a full floating subview for a simple layer.  The document view is a custom view that draws a background. The clipview doesn't (I didn't think it was possible).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the solution was simple.

The layer was masked by the scrollview's subviews (namely, its `contentView`). I simply changed the layer `zPosition` property to a positive value, and the layer now shows.